# Efficient updating with temporal table using C# and EF Core

Tags: c#, temporal-tables, ef-core-6.0

We are using EF Core 6.0 with a temporal table. But on every `_context.Update();`, a new record appears in the history table, even if no different data was added in any property.

How can I do that so no new entry will be added if no property has changed?

Comment: When a database has a primary key(s) only one row is created for the unique key and you must use Update to change an existing value or insert to add a new value.

Comment: yes, I use the PK to get the object, than modify it's properties from the Dto and call _context.Update() and _context.SaveChanges(); That is a normal update process, which called many times with no property changes at all creates many record in temporal table.

Comment: @JaczuraZoltán are you sure that the `Id` property - or whatever field is the PK - of the object loaded is not touched before saving changes?

Comment: You are looking at the history table not the actual database table.  So don't you want to see in the history every time a row changes?

Comment: The PK property cannot be touched, and not touched at all, only the updatable properties are modified line by line.  So when a property is changed it appears on the normal table and a new record appears in the history table. That works fine.  I don't want to see a new record in the history table when no property changed at all, so there is no modification in the property. (The user loaded and saved the very same content)

Comment: Practically i would like to prevent these code snippet to insert into every Update call:

 var changed = _context.Entry(obj).Properties.Any(x => x.IsModified);
            if (changed) _context.Update(obj);

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior for temporal tables.  Your issue lies with your use of EF Core, which does not issue update commands unless it detects an entity has changed.  What are you doing that EF thinks an entity has changed when you're saying it has not, attaching an entity as modified without loading the current state from the DB?  You may correct that by loading the entity from the DB, then applying changes to that entity.  If nothing has effectively changed, `SaveChanges` won't issue an update command for that entity.